# show contents of textarea to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a textarea to show its content to a div by a clicking a button. I wrote a simple code that it sees for short time in div but it disappears in div and textarea quickly.

how can I correct it, for now I’m only designing the page and I want to make style for answer so I need to see content in div without connect it to server.

```
<textarea class="inBox"></textarea><button class="btn">Send</button>
```

Code link: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jackson3d/h84qu8x3/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `return false;` to the end of your method to prevent post action or change inputs type to `button`.

Your problem is in reload form by submit button click.

Answer (score 3):

See the update fiddle:

added the following code in the click function:

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

To prevent the page reload/load.

"https://jsfiddle.net/h84qu8x3/12/"

Answer (score 2):

Just Add

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in the onClick button event

[**FiddleDemo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/h84qu8x3/13/)

Answer (score 2):

Use following code

HTML

```
<form action="#">
<textarea class="inBox"></textarea><button class="btn">Send</button>
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
var inpx= $('.inBox').val();
$('#mainbox').text(inpx);
});
```

});

Answer (score 2):

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var inpx= $('.inBox').val();
    $('#mainbox').append(inpx);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, type of `button` is `submit`, so that submits the FORM. Set its type to `button`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Send</button>
```

### -jsFiddle-